# Input box right next to label

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an input box right next to a label. I used float:left and clear:right. But it makes my form look like a "staircase". The labels should stack below eachother with the subscribe-button in the center last. Where am I wrong?

Fiddle attached... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/94yp99jo/2/)

HTML

```
<h1>Register now</h1>

        <div class="newsletter-name">
            <label>Name:</label>
                <label><input name="name" type="text" value=
                ""></label>
        </div>

        <div class="newsletter-email">
            <label>Email:</label>

                <label><input name="email" type="text" value=
                ""></label>

        </div>

        <div class="newsletter-subscribe">
            <input name="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.newsletter-form {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}

.newsletter-form h1 {
    font-size:26px;
}   

.newsletter-name {
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.newsletter-name label {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin-right:1.0em;
    display: block;
    width:3em;
}

.newsletter-name input {
    border:1px dotted #000000;
}

.newsletter-email {
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.newsletter-email label {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin-right:1.0em;
    display: block;
    width:3em;
}

.newsletter-email input {
    border:1px dotted #000000;
}

.newsletter-subscribe {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.entry-field-newsletter {
    padding-left:30px
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/94yp99jo/4/) what you wnat?

Comment: Glad that it helped..:) i've added  that as my answer..could you please mark the answer as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/94yp99jo/4/)

I've added a `clear:both` to `.newsletter-email` and `.newsletter-name`

`clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

**CSS**

```
.newsletter-form {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
.newsletter-form h1 {
    font-size:26px;
}
.newsletter-name {
    clear: both;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.newsletter-name label {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1.0em;
    display: block;
    width:3em;
}
.newsletter-name input {
    border:1px dotted #000000;
}
.newsletter-email {
    clear: both;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.newsletter-email label {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1.0em;
    display: block;
    width:3em;
}
.newsletter-email input {
    border:1px dotted #000000;
}
.newsletter-subscribe {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.entry-field-newsletter {
    padding-left:30px
}
```